# GSON JSON parsing returns null

Tags: android, json, gson

This is the code I have been trying to parse using GSON, from an array of custom type.

```
    class Message{
         String username;
         String text;
         String user_pic;
         public Message(String un, String msg){
             username=un; text=msg;
         }
    }   

    Message[] messages = new Message[2];
    messages[0]=new Message("rory","hi");
    messages[1]=new Message("van","where's my money!");
    String JSON2 = new Gson().toJson(messages, Message[].class);
```

returns "[null,null]"

Comment: i ran your code, but it works. does it return null array truly?

Comment: it returns the string I provided, JSON2 = "[null,null]", as I ran it with debug. really don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

couldn't get GSON to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert your custom array to Json string using Gson library.

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJsonTree(messages).toString();
```

Refer [Gson API documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) for more details. Hope this will be helpful.